# How to get String value from Rep[String] using slick 3 in Play scala?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0, playframework-2.5

I have a DAO method which returns an Future Option, it is like this:

```
def authenticate(username: String, password: String): Future[Option[User]] = {

    val query = db.run(Users.filter(x => x.email === username && password.isBcrypted(x.password.toString())).result).map(_.headOption)
    query
  }
```

The problem is, password.isBcrypted(x.password.toString()), where I am trying to get value of x.password, but it is Rep[String], I tried to find how to get the value from Rep[T] but couldnt come up with a solution.

Is there a good way for this?

---

### Solution

```
val query = db.run(Users.filter(_.email === username).result.map(_.headOption.filter(user => password.isBcrypted(user.password)))).map(_.headOption)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check password after getting the `result`:

```
Users.filter(_.email === username).result.map(_.headOption.filter(user => password.isBcrypted(user.password)))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works smoothly, but I still have a question as to what is Rep in slick? Is there any easier way to get value out of it?

Comment: `Rep` is a way of representing a column in Slick. It is not something that is used to get values, but something that is used to write queries.